# How to ALTER sqlite column (iPhone)?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, sqlite

For the iPhone, since sqlite3 doesn't support ALTER for a column, how do I change the data type of a column on a table that needs to preserve its data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQLite uses Manifest (Dynamic) typing.  The column types are a guide only and so Altering the column data type is not necessary. [Column Affinity](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#affinity) is used just to provide compatibility with statically typed databases.

From the [SQLite documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q3):

> SQLite uses dynamic typing. It does
>   not enforce data type constraints. Any
>   data can be inserted into any column.
>   You can put arbitrary length strings
>   into integer columns, floating point
>   numbers in boolean columns, or dates
>   in character columns. The datatype you
>   assign to a column in the CREATE TABLE
>   command does not restrict what data
>   can be put into that column...
>
> SQLite does use the declared type of a
>   column as a hint that you prefer
>   values in that format. So, for
>   example, if a column is of type
>   INTEGER and you try to insert a string
>   into that column, SQLite will attempt
>   to convert the string into an integer.
>   If it can, it inserts the integer
>   instead. If not, it inserts the string

They go on to say that this is not a bug but a feature.  If it is a problem for your application I guess SQlite may not be the best choice for you.

Answer (score 2):

Ash is correct, but I'd like to add that if a column's type affinity is causing problems for you (for example, if strings that look like numbers are being converted and stored inaccurately), your only option is to copy all the data to a temporary table, drop the original, recreate it with the right definition, and copy the data back.  As far as I know this is *not* considered a feature. ;^)